# How to understand DNS record is updated?

Tags: dns

One day ago, I updated my DNS records.

For example my domain name is `example.com.tr`
And the IP adress of my site is `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd`.

For now, when I ping the example.com.tr from my commandline window, it returns:

> Ping request could not find host example.com.tr . Please check the name and try again.

Is it because the DNS server has not updated my record yet?
Or could there be any other problems? How much do I have to wait for this update process?

Comment: It's almost certainly something wrong. If you post the actual domain name, we can troubleshoot it for you. Otherwise, start out querying the root nameservers to find the nameservers for the TLD your domain is registered in. Then see if those nameservers have your domain's nameservers. Then check your domain's nameservers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ping uses a protocol called ICMP.  Many service providers disable ICMP and many firewalls block ICMP.  To see if this is specific to the URL (example.com.tr), ping the address aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd  If you receive a notification that the address could not be found, ICMP is likely being blocked.  This does not mean something is broken, it has likely been configured this way for security reasons.  To identify where that is happening, try using traceroute.  If the ping completes, you are likely narrowing this down to an issue with your DNS record.

TYPICALLY, DNS updates are expected completed in 48 hours.  Remember this is a process of notifying databases worldwide that there is a change, and that the change is aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd now points to example.com.tr

In the DNS record there are several lines available.  As you mentioned an IPv4 address (aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd) You will want to make sure that the address in the A record points to your domain (example.com.tr).

If you have any further questions about this, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for helpful explanation.
I use tracert and it returns Unable to resolve target system. I think I need to wait a bit more...

Comment: When you use ping and tracroute to the IP address (aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd) of the target system does it show up?

Comment: ping aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd and tracert aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd are working succesfully but ping www.example.com.tr or tracert www.example.com.tr indicates that ping request can not found the host and tracert unable to resolve system name...

Comment: That clearly shows that this is a function of the name lookup.  This likely comes down to propagation of domain records.